# Query regarding IPSET

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

With iptables version 1.4.21 and RHEL7.2 , I have been observing a difference in ipsets. 
It seems that the ipsets are displayed as follows:-

```
root@system> ipset list
Name: BlockList
Type: hash:ip
**Revision: 1**
Header: family inet hashsize 4096 maxelem 2147483648
Size in memory: 65680
References: 0
Members:

Name: BlockList2
Type: hash:ip
**Revision: 3**
Header: family inet hashsize 4096 maxelem 2147483648
Size in memory: 65680
References: 0
Members:
```

What is the significance of this revision? Could anyone let me know.

On RHEL6.6 and an older version of iptables 1.4.7, I could get this as the output:-

```
Name: myset
Type: hash:net
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 16848
References: 0
Members:
27.8.0.0/13
58.16.0.0/15
14.144.0.0/12
```

Here I can see that there is no such thing called Revision.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I edited your question to highlight the 'output': if you look at the markdown adding thsoe spaces in (or using the web button "{" on the little editor gui) can make your questions easier to read and  then hopefully someone can help you find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you I have no idea what it represents but as per ipset Changelog you can see this:

```
6.14
The set type revision number is added to the header part of listing
Help prints list type revision and terse description
Include supported revisions in module description
```

Not sure if this helps. I can't find any other infos on their official web page about this. Sorry I can't help you more!